# How to add a button/menu to the reply window of Outlook 2003

Tags: vb.net, vba, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I know how to create a button, but I want it to be on the reply window or at least on every new mail item window (reply or new mail). I can't find any way to do that. Does it have anything to do with handlers or explorers? Is it even possible on outlook 2003, or Microsoft did not provide any object to do that?

Environnement : Visual studio 2008 => add-in for outlook 2003 on xp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the button, check that the MailItem.Sent property is false.